# Is there any way to reset R.java for android application development on eclipse?

Tags: android, r.java-file

`R.java` is not responding. I made 4 layouts in res/layout and it took 3 layouts but not responding for 4th

If i edit the `R.java` will it stop regenerating the code ?

Comment: no, the rendering of the code is done by the aapt tool run by the eclipse plugin after every resource change saved to the env.
what do you mean R.java is not responsing ? it's a class, static for that matter with static inner classes that contains static fields, what exactly it should respond to ?

Comment: Sorry for wrong terminology i meant that R.java is not picking up the changes i am making  with layouts. Is there any way to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all of your resources for errors. Make sure there are no subfolders in your Drawable folders, make sure all resource names contain only lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores for their names, make sure any ninepatch images you're using are correct (use tools/draw9patch in your SDK folder). Clean your project after any changes to these.

If you can't find anything that looks out of place, start removing any resources you've added, removing the most recent first, and cleaning after each removal, and see if the problem goes away. If it goes away after pulling one out, then there's a problem with that resource.

Answer (score 4):

Project > Clean...
This will force Eclipse to delete and regenerate the R.java file.

Comment: It's supposed to. Then it regenerates.

Comment: If this didn't work, review your SDK setup. There may be something wrong. Try updating your ADT eclipse plugin and your Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across same problem.  Delete

```
Import android.R;
```

This should fix the problem and have all references re validated.